# UnicodeDecoderror: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, c, phylogeny, dendropy

I am not a programmer, not even advanced in programming, so please be less mad about my question :D

The thing is that I am a biologist, and I just started to learn programming a bit (I have to). I was trying to install `dendropy/sumtrees` via python using the description [in this site](https://pythonhosted.org/DendroPy/programs/sumtrees.html).

I used the

```
c:\...\DendroPy-4.0.3>c:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install -U dendropy
```

in c prompt, and I got the message:

```
UnicodeDecoderror: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can anybody help me? (using words you are using for a monkey to understand the basics of quantum physics...)
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Looks like a bug in the installation script of `DendroPy`. You wouldn't happen to have an `á` in your Windows username, would you?

Comment: @Cameron it looks like maybe a `é` (`'\xE9'`). Can you do less obfuscation on your `c:\...\ ` path?

Comment: I agree with @NickT, it looks like the install path contains a non-[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character.

Comment: change all your ``\\` with `/` chars

Comment: @RNar he's on Windows, presumably in `cmd` or PowerShell. Backslash is correct.

Comment: What's the full error trace?